# How to edit/change/modify the Syntax Highlighting Color in VS Code

Tags: autohotkey, syntax-highlighting, markdown, color-theme, visual-studio-code

How to edit/change/modify the Syntax Highlighting Color in VS Code, ie for Autohotkey and/or Markdown languages?

For example: Im using the High Contrast theme (black background), and in that theme, the hash/sharp "#" symbol is colored dark blue, but I want to change it to some other color. For autohotkey, the commands "if then else" are in purple, but I want to change it to some other else.

I'm trying to search in the Preference > Settings, seems nothing there is related to it?

Or are there any VSCode extensions that's capable of modifying that?

Thanks,
Faye

Comment: [Themes, Snippets and Colorizers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers)

Answer (score 0):

When I want to make changes to syntax and colour I navigate to one of the default themes and make changes there.

eg. I want to change the default Dark+ theme so I navigate and open the .json file and edit it there;

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes\dark_plus.json
```

If you have downloaded an extension theme you need to navigate to your user folder and edit the .json file there.

eg. I want to change the default Dark+WoW theme so I navigate and open the .json file and edit it there;

```
C:\Users\whatEverYourUserNameIs\.vscode\extensions\Septh.wow-bundle-1.2.5\themes\dark_plus_wow.json
```

**Always make a copy of the original file** in case the changes you make cause the universe to explode and you need to start over again; (it is the only way I seem to learn).